# Place button inside page header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Supose I had this code im one of my views of my spring project:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Example page header <small>Subtext for header</small></h1>
</div>
```

(without the subtext). How I could place a group of buttons like this one:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

inside the `page-header`, aligned to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well make them float right by using bootstrap's `pull-right` class:

```css
.header-btn-group{
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="page-header">
  <div class="btn-group pull-right header-btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
  <h1>Example page header <small>Subtext for header</small></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: with this solution the buttons will not be aligned with the text (they will be placed over the line which is located below the text). Is there a way to fix that and make the buttons stay in the same place of the text (but in the other corner)?

Comment: Unfortunately you will have to fine-tune the position manually.

Comment: I assume this should be done with some css. Can you tell me which css code I can use to do this inline? I mean, can I do this with one single and short css instruction?

Comment: Yes, just give the button group a `top: 2px;` or something to push it down. See my updated answer.